# Numpy sorting array (sparse)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to work out why this code doesn't sort the array...

## Arbitrary vector.

```
x = array([[3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2]])
xCoo = sps.coo_matrix(x)
perm = np.argsort(x)
xCoo.col = perm[xCoo.col]
print(xCoo.toarray()) # array([3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2])
```

I'm not sure what I've misunderstood.  What's the correct way to do this?

Thank you.

P.S. I'm aware that I can just call sort on the array; however, I went to apply this same permutation over and over again.

Comment: What is `sps`?  and what is the purpose of `coo_matrix`?  It seems like it should just be something like:  `a = np.array([...]); idx = np.argsort(a); sorted_a = a[idx]` ...

Comment: `sps` is from: `import scipy.sparse as sps`.  `coo_matrix` is a type of sparse matrix.

Comment: Is `x` always going to be a 1 row 2d array?  How many rows in `xCoo`?  Is the goal to sort the columns of many sparse matrices, all with the same `perm`?

Comment: I made a small typo, x is just meant to be a 1D array. xCoo will be the same dombaions as x.  Yes, the goal is to apply perm over and over to different 1D matrices!

Answer (score 2):

The first complication is the `np.argsort(x)` returns a 2d array.  Lets do the sort on flattened `x` to get a simpler 1d `perm`:

```
In [1118]: perm=np.argsort(x,None)

In [1119]: perm
Out[1119]: 
array([10, 17,  1, 14, 13,  9, 16,  0,  6,  8,  5, 11,  2, 15,  7,  3, 12,
        4], dtype=int32)
```

this sorts `x` as we expect, right?

```
In [1120]: x[:,perm]
Out[1120]: array([[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

now apply it in the same way to `xCoo`, except we have to convert it to `lil` format.  `coo` format isn't subscriptable:

```
In [1121]: xCoo.tolil()[:,perm].A
Out[1121]: array([[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

To apply `perm` directly to the attributes of `xCoo`, we need to do another sort:

```
xCoo.col = np.argsort(perm)[xCoo.col]   # <====
```

This works for multirow `xCoo` with zeros.

You can also sort the data:

```
xCoo.data = xCoo.data[perm[xCoo.col]]
```

These work here, but they need more testing.